# Listview shows 4 records. DataGridView shows 3 records?

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

Originally I was using a Listview to display the oracle results however I've recently had to switch to a datagridview to work with the results a bit more than the Listview allows.  Since switching to a datagrid however I am getting less results.  I've been stepping through the code and haven't been able to determine where the problem occurs.

This is frmMain where I display the results.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtpicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dtpicker.CustomFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";
    string VoidDate = dtpicker.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

    DataTable resultnew = new DataTable();

    resultnew.Load(oracleConnection.GetVoidDGV(VoidDate));

    if (resultnew != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DBNull.Value;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = resultnew;
        SetupDGV();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No History Found");
    }
}

private void SetupDGV()
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Heat Run";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Lot Number";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Serial Number";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Date";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Void Location";
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Void Length";
    dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Employee ID";

    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

And this is my class

```
public OleDbDataReader GetVoidDGV(string VoidDate)
{
    var conn = new OleDbConnection(oracleConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string query =  "SELECT HEAT_RUN_NO, LOT_NO, SERIAL_NO, TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as DATE_NO_TIME, VOID_LOC, cast(VOID_LENGTH as int) as VOID_LENGTH, EMPL_ID ";
           query += "FROM MPCS.BRAZE_VOIDS ";
           query += "WHERE TRUNC(DATE_TIME) = TO_DATE(?, 'dd-MON-yy')";
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DATE_TIME", VoidDate);
    rsMPCS = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rsMPCS.Read();
    return rsMPCS;
}
```

Their should be 4 results.  DGV only shows 3.  Listview shows the 4.

This is just a screenshot of the 4 in Oracle SQL Developer.  I've highlighted the one that isn't displayed.  Line 1.

[image: 3of4]

Comment: Can you share SetupDGV() code?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev Added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the first line because you are making a call to `rsMPCS.Read();` before returning the reader, which advances the "record pointer", so only the subsequent records are loaded.

Remove that line and it will work.

Comment: I'm upset I missed it, but happy it was a simple fix.  Thanks so much stuartd.